# Which opening contains this trap?

Tags: tactics, opening-traps, pins, patterns, fork

The sequence of moves for White is Nd5, Bb4, and then Bb5, capturing the queen by a fork. The pattern should look something like the below position. I remember that I've seen this trap in some opening, but I can not remember which is it. It is probably some Sicilian sideline.

```
[FEN "rnb1kbnr/pp2pppp/2q5/1B1N4/1B6/8/PPPPPPPP/R2QK1NR w KQkq - 0 1"]
```

Comment: I vaguely recognize this from some lines in the open sicilian, but I doubt that black's queen is on c6. I find it much more likely that black's queen is on b6 and that white moves Nd5.

Comment: That's a pin, not a fork.

Comment: @Acccumulation the trap is not the pin, but the fork that follows afterward if the queen takes the bishop.

Comment: @Acccumulation actually before moderation there was a term 'pork', which means a pin and a fork at the same time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is also one line in the Modern, which pretty much matches your setup:

```
[FEN "rnbqkbnr/pppppppp/8/8/8/8/PPPPPPPP/RNBQKBNR w KQkq - 0 1"]

1. e4 g6 2. d4 Bg7 3. Nc3 c5 4. dxc5 Qa5 5. Bd2 Qxc5 6. Nd5 Nf6?? {for instance, there are several moves losing the queen. The main move seems to be 6. ..Na6} 7. Bb4 Qc6 8. Bb5
```

Answer (score 6):

Adding to Philip's answer, I more remember it from the Scandinavian, because there the bQ gets out early anyway and it takes much less patzer moves to irreversibly trap it this way. Example:

```
[FEN "rnbqkbnr/pppppppp/8/8/8/8/PPPPPPPP/RNBQKBNR w KQkq - 0 1"]

1.e4 d5 2.exd5 Qxd5 3.Nc3 Qe5+ {or Qe6+, still 70 games up to here on Lichess} 4.Be2 Qf6? 5.Nd5!? Qc6?? 6.Bb5! 1-0
```

For a definite answer, the move/board pattern "Nd5 Qc6 Bb5" should be searchable (at least with Costeff's CQL tool).

Answer (score 5):

A configuration of pieces like this can occur in many Sicilian sidelines, or with colors reversed in the English. For example 1. e4 c5 2.Nf3  Nc6 3.Bb5 g6 4.Nc3 Qb6 5.Nd5, or 1.c4 e5 2.Nc3 Bb4 3.Qb3 Nc6 4.g3 Nd4. I am not aware that it has a name, or is even of much importance. Although the Knight makes a slightly surprizing advance that seems to gain a tempo, the opponent can just retreat the Queen to her original square and then drive the Knight back with their e-Pawn. Nobody gains or loses anything. There can be an exception if one of the e-Pawns has alredy made a double jump, in which case the Queen move would be a oversight.